# Convert line-wise block of program output to CSV while removing line headers

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk, sed, csv

Need your help, my command output is :

```
Server1:  
CPU(S):  8  
RAM: 24  
Socket: 2  

Server2:  
CPU(S):  16   
RAM: 32   
Socket: 5
```

Desired Output:

```
Server1:,8,24,2  
Server2:,16,32,5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
awk '
  NF==1 { printf "%s%s", NR==1 ? "" : ORS, $1 }
  NF==2 { printf ",%s", $2 }
  END   { printf "%s", ORS }
' file
```

- If the line contains one field:

  - print a newline if this is not the first line
  - print field1
- If the line contains two fields, print a comma and field2
- Finally, print a newline

Comment: Thankyou!! it worked

Comment: `printf "%s", ORS` = `print ""`.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk -v RS= -v OFS=',' '{print $1, $3, $5, $7}' file
Server1:,8,24,2
Server2:,16,32,5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# will be used to remember the previous line
b=;
while read -r a; do 
 # if the previous line was empty, then this line is a title line
 if [ "$b" == "" ]; 
  then echo;
  echo -n $a; 
 # else only output everything after ": "
 else IFS=": " read -r _ digs <<< "$a"; 
 # don't want to output a comma for a blank line
  if [ "$a" != "" ]; 
   then echo -n ,$digs;
  fi;
 fi;
 b=$a; 
done < 2
```

Output:

```
　
Server1:,8,24,2  
Server2:,16,32,5
```

If you'd like to get rid of the space in the beginning or add a blank line at the end, there are a couple of ways to do it, that would make this script a bit more complicated.  Let me know if you can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: the output comes in a single line.i want it. Server1 details in one line and server2 details in next line.

Comment: ? I don't understand what you mean...

Comment: Hi Alex, If we have more than 2 server info this is not working.

Comment: Can you post an example of a text for which this does not work?

Comment: See [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice) for the main problem with this script and run it through http://shellcheck.net for others.

Answer (score 0):

`sed` solution.

```
$ cat file.txt
Server1:
CPU(S):  8
RAM: 24
Socket: 2

Server2:
CPU(S):  16
RAM: 32
Socket: 5
$ sed -n '/^Server/{s/ *$//;N;s/\n.*: */,/;s/ *$//;N;s/\n.*: */,/;s/ *$//;N;s/\n.*: */,/;p}' file.txt
Server1:,8,24,2
Server2:,16,32,5
$
```

Answer (score 0):

With a sufficiently recent<sup>1</sup> version of [Miller](https://johnkerl.org/miller/doc/index.html)

```
mlr --idkvp --irs '\n\n' --ifs '\n' --ips ':' --ocsvlite --headerless-csv-output \
  clean-whitespace then put 'x=$[[1]]; $[[1]]="1"; $1=x' then remove-empty-columns \
  inputfile
```

Explanation:

- `--idkvp --irs '\n\n' --ifs '\n' --ips ':' --ocsvlite --headerless-csv-output` set the input format to paragraph mode with key-value pairs separated by the colon character and one field per line; set the output format to `csvlite` and suppress printing of the field name header
- `clean-whitespace` strip leading and trailing whitespace form the field values
- `put 'x=$[[1]]; $[[1]]="1"; $1=x'` set the value of the first field equal to its name<sup>2</sup> and set its name to "1" . The latter is important since it homogenizes the records - otherwise Miller prints each record as a separate CSV block, even when `--headerless-csv-output` is in effect.
- `remove-empty-columns` since with `--irs '\n\n' --ifs '\n'`, a *single* newline after the final record is treated as a trailing empty field - this kludge removes it

If you want the `:` to be preserved as part of the first field value, then change `$1=x` to `$1=x.":"` in the `put` clause.

Testing:

```
$ ~/src/miller/c/mlr --idkvp --irs '\n\n' --ifs '\n' --ips ':' --ocsvlite --headerless-csv-output \
>   clean-whitespace then put 'x=$[[1]]; $[[1]]="1"; $1=x' then remove-empty-columns \
>   inputfile
Server1,8,24,2
Server2,16,32,5
```

or preserving the `:` in the server name:

```
$ ~/src/miller/c/mlr --idkvp --irs '\n\n' --ifs '\n' --ips ':' --ocsvlite --headerless-csv-output \
>   clean-whitespace then put 'x=$[[1]]; $[[1]]="1"; $1=x.":"' then remove-empty-columns \
>   inputfile
Server1:,8,24,2
Server2:,16,32,5
```

---

<sup>1</sup> works in Miller 5.6.2-dev but not in Miller 5.3.0

<sup>2</sup> note that although it looks like it should be possible to do the name-value swap *without* the temporary variable as

```
 put '$[ $[[1]] ]=$[[1]]; $[[1]]="1"'
```

this appears to have the side effect of creating an additional empty-valued in-stream variable with a non-printable name.

Answer (score 0):

Using awk in paragraph mode :

```
awk -v RS= 'gsub(/\n[^:]+: */, ",")' file

 Server1:,8,24,2
 Server2:,16,32,5
```